# Slidedown form on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show form when user clickes on the button. Form is showing up but there seems to be a bug for a second. form is centered when the slide up function is executing and when it is done it fits normally to the page.

Here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clicked').on('click', function(e) {
        var current = $(e.target).next();
        var show = current.hasClass('hidden');

        if (show) {
            current.hide();
            current.removeClass('hidden');
            current.slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            current.slideUp('slow', function() {
                current.addClass('hidden');
                current.slideUp('slow');
            });
        }

    })
});
```

I do not think there is any bug in js code, most likely missing something in css.

Have a look here and click on blue button "Click Here" http://codepen.io/nikasv/pen/vKEEZr

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.trip-form{
    width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

will do the trick even with the shaking you experience :)

Comment: Thanks, not shaking any more :))

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set width of class "trip-form" to 100%.

Comment: Thanks, works great for width, but now the height is a problem as well :( slightly shaking from down to up. Tried to remove margin but it messes up the form and I actually need it to separate it from upper text and image.